# How to RSpec test setting of the error notice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Normally I create my controller actions like this:

```
  def destroy
    if @account.destroy
      flash[:success] = "Account deleted!"
    else
      flash[:error] = "Could not delete account!"
    end
    redirect_to(:back)
  end
```

Obviously, in most cases, you will not run into any fails of that request. How should I test that the error flash gets set in case `@account.destroy` would somehow return false? Is there a way to mock that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect that the destroy method should always return `true`, it would be better to have `@account.destroy!`. This way an exception will be raised if the `destroy` failed and you (as the application owner) would get notified to see why it did (unexpectedly) fail.

```
def destroy
    @account.destroy!
    flash[:success] = "Account deleted!"
    redirect_to(:back)
end
```

But to answer your original question, you can always stub the return of a method using `allow_any_instance_of(Account).to receive(:destroy).and_return(false)`

Comment: just one more question, what would be a valid reason for such a switch? I'd expect that there could be problems with database, or record not found. Are there any other reasons such a call could/would fail that require such a structure?

Comment: Usually the `destroy` call returns false if you have [some destroy callbacks on your model that were halted](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#destroying-an-object). The other 2 cases you mentioned will ultimately raise an error even if you are just using `destroy` (if the record is not found, then you will get `undefined method destroy for nil:NilClass`, if you have some foreign key restriction, an error will also be raise with a database foreign key violation)